# QGIS. Combining points data on a map with attributes in polygons

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, csv, point-in-polygon

I have a project where I'm trying to combine flood risk data to a list of postcode (/zipcode) data. The postcode data is a csv that contains each postcode's easting, northing, longitude, and latitude values, and the flood risk data is a shape file containing polygon data that has a risk attribute (very low, low, medium, high). So I want my end result to be a csv containing every postcode and it's flood risk (even if there isn't one).

I've imported the flood risk shape file `(Layer -> Add layer -> Add vector layer)` which shows the whole country and polygons where there's a flood risk. I've also imported the csv file `(Layer -> Add layer -> Add delimited text layer)` and all the points on the map are correctly aligned (I've aligned the X and Y with it's easting and northing values as the coordinates in the flood data use those values).

The CRS of the flood risk data is `EPSG:27700 - OSGB36 / British National Grid`. The csv is imported with the same CRS. I've exported the csv into a shape file and this also uses the same CRS.

To join them together I've used `Vector -> Data Management Tools -> Join attribute by location` with the parameters -

```
Join to features in: The Postcode shape file (exported from csv)
By comparing to: Flood shape file.
Join type: one-to-many.
```

I did get a warning saying `"No spatial index exists for join layer, performance will be severely degraded"`

However when running the join, it took about 40 minutes in the execution for the blue bar to go away, and now it's stuck on 0% with "Running. Estimated time remaining: 40749:40 minutes"

I just wanted to know if I'm doing this correctly? I understand that it should take a while as there are 2.6 million postcodes to go through, but 28 days (which is what I think it means) seems like I've made a mistake somewhere.

I'm new to QGIS.

Comment: What prevents you from creating spatial indexes first?

Comment: After importing your vector layer and your CSV layer with mouse right click on each one, go to Layer properties, then go to Source and in geometry section click create spatial index.

Comment: This resolved the issue. Thanks.